# Unable to access jar file with drag&drop on a batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I created a batch file to run an executable jar with some options. The code in the batch is

```
java -jar target/%jar% %1
```

When I just run the .bat file, the jar gets executed as expected and the JAVA program generates an appropriate warning because of the missing parameter. Unfortunately, when I drop a file on the batch I get

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile target/someprogram.jar
```

The error does not occur when I specify the input file in the .bat itself, only with drag&drop. I also tried to echo the command and parameters before executing and everything seems to go as expected even with drag&drop.

Any ideas how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, try an absolute path to the jar.

Comment: It works with an absolute path, which is a bit unfortunate as I planned to use the .bat on multiple machines with different absolute paths...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suspect is that the 'current path' is relative to the file being dragged rather than the bat.

There might be a way to get the pwd of the bat...

confirmed:

```
set PWD=%~dp0
echo %PWD%
pause
```

save this as whatever.bat, then drag and drop a file from another directory to it. You'll see that the operating directory is that of the file dragged, but %~dp0 will give you the directory where the bat resides.

Comment: Funny I thought about that possibility as well and echoed a `chdir` which returned the correct directory.